# How to call a function with "int" argument in C?

Tags: c

I have been writing code with C and I needed to define a function with arguments of the type `int`. Basically, I want to make a check on a number, however, this number might be 13, 15, or 16 digits. I've divided the number into an array so I can have every digit alone and I've created a `for` loop in order to do some processing on. I just want the maximum number of the `for` loop to be a variable.

What I had tried is writing a `for` loop but with the maximum number as a variable `R` not a number. The problem is that the program doesn't compile unless I initialize the variable `R` value which is to be taken when calling the function in the main function. I've attached the code to you and I will be glad if anyone can help me with that. Thanks.

```c
int CHECK(int R);                        // Function Prototype
int main() {
    ...
    ...
    var = CHECK(15);               // Function called
    ...
    ...
```

```c
int CHECK(int R);                 // Function definition
{
    int R;    
    for  (int z = 1; z <= R; z += 2) {
        if (array[z] <= 4)
        ...
```

This error appears when I compile the file:

```
credit.c:56:9: note: initialize the variable 'R' to silence this warning
int R;    
    ^
     = 0
1 error generated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'credit' failed
make: *** [credit] Error 1
```

If I have to define the `R` variable than his value will not be changed and I cannot `R` as an operation result. What shall I do?

Comment: you can't have the variable names, in the same function.

Comment: Redefining `int R` causes a compiler error in Visual C even when it is initialised as say `int R = 3;` because it has the same scope as the function parameter. Also I suspect array overrun by using `for(int z = 1; z <= R; z += 2)` which should probably be `for(int z = 0; z < R; z += 2)`

Comment: @JuniusL. you can, if the second definition has a smaller scope (for example inside a `for` loop), in which case it "shadows" the first definition.

Comment: Something is very screwey here.  The semicolon at the end of `int CHECK(int R);` in the purported definition of `CHECK` makes that a *declaration*, not a definition.  Both that and the following block must therefore appear inside a larger function, else the block would be erroneous, so if function `CHECK` is defined at all then its actual definition must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is called "variable shadowing":

Your function parameter is named `R`, but in your function you also have a local variable with the same name.

The local variable "overshadows" the parameter, so every time you write `R` in code after the line `int R;`, you are actually referencing the variable and **not** the parameter!

Just delete the local variable since you are not using it anyway, and your code will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve with your code at all, but I think the problem is that you declared the variable `R` twice. Once as a parameter for the function and once in the functions' body.

```
int CHECK(int R);                 // this defines R
{
int R;                            // this also defines R
for  (int z = 1; z <= R; z += 2) {
if (array[z] <= 4)
```

So you should just try removing the second line:

```
int CHECK(int R);
{
for  (int z = 1; z <= R; z += 2) {
if (array[z] <= 4)
```

Comment: My target is to create arrays which might be array[13], array[15], or array[16]. So each one of these will go through the same process but with different numbers. Hence, I created the function CHECK() which will receive a number when it is called. That number is "R" however, "R" should not be initialized at the moment it should only take a number when the function is called.                                                                             So I will call the function three times with three different input numbers 13, 15, or 16

Comment: @HazemWaddah Well, that's what function parameters are all about. Executing some code with different values for the same variable(s). Does this solve your problem?